# WiX 3.11 Bootstrapper error message displays over another error message

Tags: bootstrapper, wix3.11

So I'm using the WiX bootstrapper to install a wix created MSI (wpf/c#) along with two other installers. The problem is if the user uninstalls one of the other programs, my program will not be uninstalled and I'm left with a generic (and broken) "0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation."

I would like to have a custom message here but I want to figure out why it's displaying two messages in this buggy way first, and I'm still unsure on how to do a custom error message in the bootstrapper.

The main reason I'm asking this question is because WiX is actually displaying TWO error messages one on top of the other (with the one I mentioned previously being on top.)  If you click the close button but don't let go until you drag off the button to prevent it from actually closing, it displays another error message "One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more information see the log file." This is the message that you can barely see the top of behind the other one and I'm wondering why it's displaying two messages at once in a broken way.  Here's what the errors look like in wix. The custom action in this case is returning ActionResult.Failure.

[image: WiX bootstrapper displaying one error message on top of another]

Comment: I would do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/enable-windows-installer-logging) first.  Start with very little logging and work your way up from there.  The bug might be in the bootstrapper but I doubt it.  Verbose mode SUCKS and it is difficult to find errors..

Comment: I'll try it. I looked at the logs for the bootstrapper and the other one as well and couldn't really decipher why it was doing this still.  But I did see an actual error message in there which was logged by the custom action due to localdb being missing "Exception: Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name." Other than that I don't really know what to look for in these logs. I can change the logging level though to see what else may show up.

Comment: If it were me.. because it is a path issue.. I would try to use the systeminternals process monitor to see what the heck it is trying to do.  If you aren't familiar with the app, its a pain the learn how to manage the filters.  Once you do, you have an invaluable tool for writing installers (amongst other things).  I wrote installers for over 5 years.

Comment: So basically we are trying to extract user data since we will want to use that for the next version when installed, etc. I should have been more clear but it's localdb that has to be missing for this to happen. Since localdb can't be opened it throws an exception and is caught in a try catch within the custom action and we return ActionResult.Failure.  But I'm having trouble with these weird double errors ever since we converted from a normal msi installer to the bootstrapper. If what you said still applies just let me know. I've been dealing with WiX for a while but it still confuses me lol..

Comment: I would be in the same boat as you.  I have written a few installers using WiX.. straight MSI is a lot more work but easier to understand when it isn't working.   it still confuses me too! :-P .. sorry I can't help much more..

Comment: Well thanks for trying! This might have to be on the backburner for now for when I have time to learn WiX more thoroughly.